# Firestorage download urls not working as img sources

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using getDownloadURL from fire storage to get a url for any image that is uploaded on to the server. But when I try to display the images in my img element source, it returns a blank icon instead of the actual image. The image even on firestorage has trouble rendering and when its opened, its just a white square instead of the image. The function is the sendImage function in the code. Ive also added CORS configuration to my google cloud shell and changed the meta data multiple times, and yes the images do have tokens and the rules are fine. Any help .[image: ][1]]

[image: Image not loading in React App]

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faPaperclip, faImage, faPaperPlane } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { doc, db } from '../firebase'
import { arrayUnion, onSnapshot, setDoc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import ChatContext from '../Context/ChatContext'
import { AuthContext } from '../Context/AuthContext'
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
const Chat = () => {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const {data} = useContext(ChatContext)
  const [file, setFile] = useState()
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState()
  const aref = useRef(null)
  const scrollRef = useRef(null)
  const photo = '013bfa05b2955d0bff2823c2f3304e1838ac30801c.jpg'
  const storage = getStorage()
  const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${photo}`)
  const metadata = {
    contentDisposition: 'inline',
    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const unSub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "messages", data.chatId), (doc) => {
      doc.exists() && setMessages(doc.data().messages);
    });
    return () => {
      unSub();
    };
  }, [data.chatId]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    scrollToBottom() 
  }, [messages])

  const sendImage = async() =>{
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

    await uploadTask.on(
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }, 
      async() => {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
        await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async(downloadURL) => {
          await updateDoc(doc(db, 'messages', data.chatId), {
            messages: arrayUnion({photoURL: downloadURL})
          })
          console.log(downloadURL)
        });
      }
    );
  }
  const handleChange = (e) =>{
    setMsg({msg: e.target.value, origin: user.uid})
  }
  const sendMessage = async() =>{
    if(data.chatId!='global'){
      if(msg){
        await updateDoc(doc(db, 'messages', data.chatId), {
          messages: arrayUnion(msg)
        })
      }
    }
    if(file){
      sendImage()
    }
    aref.current.value = ''
  }
  const handleFileSelect = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    setFile({photoURL: e.target.files[0], origin: user.uid})
  }
  const scrollToBottom = () =>{
    scrollRef.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}) 
  }
  const handleKey = (e) => {
    e.code === "Enter" && sendMessage();
  };
  

  return (
    <div className='chatWrapper'>
      <button onClick={()=>sendImage()}>here</button>
      <div className="cWrapper">
    <div className="conversationProfile">
      <img className='conversationImage' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Dwayne_Johnson_2014_%28cropped%29.jpg/640px-Dwayne_Johnson_2014_%28cropped%29.jpg" alt=""/>
      <span>DM Name</span>
    </div>
    <div className="messages">
    {messages ? messages?.map((message) =>(
      <div className={`message ${message.origin==user.uid && 'sender'}`}>{message.msg ? message.msg : <img className='imgMSG' referrerPolicy='no-referrer' src='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mwdims.appspot.com/o/images%2F013bfa05b2955d0bff2823c2f3304e1838ac30801c.jpg?alt=media&token=a95f8bd2-97fe-4bfa-a7d5-36772407c418"
      '></img>}</div>
            )) : <div className='placeHolder'>Say Something </div>}
      <div ref={scrollRef} style={{visibility: 'hidden'}}></div>
    </div>
    <div className="chatBar">
      <input ref={aref} type="text" placeholder='Type Something...' defaultValue='' onChange={handleChange} onKeyDown={handleKey}/>
      <div className="chatFunctions">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperclip} />
        <input type='file' onChange={handleFileSelect}></input>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faImage}></FontAwesomeIcon>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} onClick={()=>sendMessage()}/>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chat
```

Comment: The image doesn't seem to be uploaded properly at first place. Can you edit your question and add code that you used to upload it?

Comment: @Dharmaraj sorry about that, fixed it

Comment: Before `const uploadTask..` can you `console.log(file)` and check if is defined? Also share a screenshot of the output